# What is the difference between the home page and landing page

Tags: website-design

Iam stuck and am not able to distinguish between the home page and a landing page; Iam very new and just don't know anything about websites; Thanks

Comment: What research have you done into this already? These aren't exactly obscure terms, I'm sure that by doing *some* research you could find these out quite easily.

Answer (score 2):

The home page is the first page that a visitor discovers when he wants to visit your site. There is usually just one.

A landing page is the first page that a visitor discovers when you want him to do something, more often when clicking on a newsletter or adwords link. There are usually a lot of landing pages according to the action you want the visitor to make and the segmentation of your visitors.

Both can be very similar but usually the home page is content and navigation oriented and the landing page is sales and call-to-action oriented.

Basically :

- Home page is when the visitor knows you.
- Landing page is when the visitor does not know you.

I recommend you two very good websites :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landing_page

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_page](https://www.google.fr/#hl=en&gs_rn=11&gs_ri=psy-ab&tok=qnSeAOXrANkSAIdN4NgC1w&cp=37&gs_id=4j&xhr=t&q=what+is+the+difference+between+landing+page+and+homepage&es_nrs=true&pf=p&safe=active&sclient=psy-ab&oq=what+is+the+differnce+between+landing&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45645796,d.d2k&fp=3ac7dbb16ac14211&biw=1600&bih=785)

Comment: IMHO your definitions of home page and landing page make incorrect assumptions. Your definitions state what you would like to happen, not what can actually happen. Any page can be the first page someone discovers. There is absolutely no reason why the  first page someone sees is the home page or a page that you would like them to land on when they follow advertisement or newsletter links. They may after all arrive through a link in a search engine, a link sent to them by a friend, etc.

Comment: Vulgarisation often leads to simplification. I am busted.